# sequence in IONIC, angularjs controller..?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have controller and execute eksekusiUlp function  like below

```
.controller('ulpCtrl', function($rootScope, $ionicPopup, tanyaService, $state) {
        $rootScope.getKat = 'UL';
        //get value from API Services 
        $rootScope.eksekusiUlp = function() {
          $rootScope.bg='#bdee8a';
          $rootScope.cekAdaSkor= function() {
          tanyaService.doApiCekAdaSkor($rootScope.getPilihSubTest, $rootScope.getNip).success(function(dataCekSkor){
            console.log(dataCekSkor['nip']);
            alert('1');
         });
       };
   alert('2');
})
```

Why my sequence alert is 2,1 not 1,2 ?
How to make it alert sequence 1 and then 2?, *i mean after get value from api then execute alert 2.

Thank You

Comment: because, it's async one... If you want in sync way you need to set your code in that way,

Comment: where is that? @Naitik

Comment: angulrjs is working in async way, means you called service and set alert('1') in service response. so it will call after service response, so code is not wait till service responded, it will execute alert('2') then after service response it will alert('1')

Comment: any trick or modification to make it happen? @Naitik

Comment: yes, ou can wait for trigger alert('2') untll response of service with $timeout   and also you can user promises.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has to do with properly understanding [JavaScript events and timing](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth) more .

plus [Understanding JavaScript Promises](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises) will help too.